# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon Customization (Copy/Paste List Item Properties)

Tags: javascript, ribbon, properties

I have a requirement to copy and paste only the properties of a document library item. There must be two button on the Edit-Form.aspx ribbon that allows me to copy and paste only the properties. I know this can be achieved by creating and deploying a custom feature with Visual Studio 2010. What ecma or java script should I call to achieve this functionality in the code.

Example:`<CommandUIHandler Command="Copy" CommandAction="javascript: ?????"/>`

Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: Do you intend to paste properties to existing items in the same document library?

Comment: Yes, Andrey u r right

Answer (score 1):

In Copy action, you should retrieve list item values and save them somewhere. Clipboard is not a good choice here, because some browsers don't accept direct access to the clipboard. Thus, I can propose HTML5 local storage, which is at the moment supported by all the modern browsers.

You can find details on HTML5 local storage here:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

For retrieving data from a list item, use JavaScript Client Object Model, as it described in the following MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007.aspx

In Paste action, you should edit existing item and pass the stored in the local storage values. You can find guidance for updating a list item in the following MSDN article:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185011.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will implement the solution and let u know

Comment: You're welcome! And please, don't hesitate to ask additional questions, if any. The question is actually quite interesting for me.